# passing a javascript variable to next jQuery mobile page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I've created a dynamic listview from database on my jQuery mobile `#page1`. 
That works all perfect. I can see a list with all items from my database (ID, name ...)

Now I want to pass the ID `garm.ID` from my database item to the next page, after I've clicked on a item in the listview.

**My JavaScript:**

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1",function(){ 
    $(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup( {
            "async": false
        } );
        $.getJSON("http://server/kas1.js", function(data) {
            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var garm = data[i];
                $.getJSON("http://server/kas2.js", function(data) {
                    var no = data[0].no;
                    $("#content-page1").append(
                        "<ul data-role=\"listview\">" +
                        "<li><a href=\"#page2\">" +
                        "<h2>Hello</h2>" +
                        "<p>Status:"+data[0].no+"</p>" +
                        "</a></li>" +
                        "</ul><br>"
                        );
                });
            }
        });
        $.ajaxSetup( {
            "async": true
        } );
    });   
});
```

You can see the line: `"<li><a href=\"#page2\">" +`

With this link you will redirect to the next page and on the next page I want to use the passed ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1",function(){ 

    $(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup( { "async": false } );


        $.getJSON("http://server/kas1.js", function(data) {
            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var garm = data[i];

                $.getJSON("http://server/kas2.js", function(data) {
                    var no = data[0].no;

                    $("#content-page1").append(
                        "<ul data-role=\"listview\">" +
                            "<li><a href='#page2?garm_id='" + garm.ID  + ">" +
                                "<h2>Hello</h2>" +
                                "<p>Status:"+data[0].no+"</p>" +
                            "</a></li>" +
                        "</ul><br>"
                    );
                });

            }
        });


        $.ajaxSetup( { "async": true } );
    });

});
```

On page two:

```
function queryStringParameters (keyValueString) {
    var query_string, whole_query_string, query_string_obj = {};
    if (typeof keyValueString === "undefined") {
        whole_query_string = window.location.search;
        if (whole_query_string[0] === "?") {
            query_string = whole_query_string.replace('?', '');
        } else {
            query_string = whole_query_string;
        }
    } else {
        query_string = keyValueString
    }
    var query_string_array = query_string.split('&');
    if (query_string !== '') {
        for (var i = 0; i < query_string_array.length; i++) {
            var query = query_string_array[i],
                query_array = query.split('=');
            query_string_obj[query_array[0]] = query_array[1] || '';
        }
        return query_string_obj;
    } else {
        return {};
    }
}


var hash = window.location.hash,
    queryString = hash.split('?')[1],
    garm = queryStringParameters(queryString),
    garm_id = garm.id;
```

Comment: Could you give me an example, how I can receive the variable on page 2? :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works:

```
'<li><a href="#page2,garmId='+ garm.ID +'">'
```

then, in page 2 you can (hopefully) parse the hashtag to get the id

Hope this helps, cheers

Comment: Some question here, could you give me an example too, how to receive the variable on page 2?